# QtCore QthreadPool segmentation fault when accessing qlibc 2.34 error __libc_start_main

Tags: qt, pthreads, glibc, qthread, libc

First post (quantum physicist, not engineer). I have a multi-threaded Qt5 application that performs perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the QThread and QtConcurrent libraries. In main(), the first call to these libraries aims to set the maxThreadCount based on command line option, settings.threads. However, the code hard crashes in Ubuntu 21.04 and 22.04 LTS due, I believe, to issue with the recent upgrade of the glibc library from 2.33 to 2.34 where a number of changes were made to libpthread, i.e. it was rolled into the libc library as described here:

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/12/17/why-glibc-234-removed-libpthread#

As the crash occurs in __libc_start_main as shown below, I have tried recompiling with gcc from 7 to 12, upgraded Qt5.14 to Qt 6.2.4 using apt without any luck. Following the Qt recommendations, all dependencies are installed.

```
Stack trace (most recent call last):
#5    Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in
#4    Object "/.../.../master/engine/build/exe/main/debug/engine", at 0x55f2c6dfbc74, in _start
#3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f0703bb2e3f, in __libc_start_main
#2    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f0703bb2d8f, in
#1    Source "/.../.../master/engine/src/main/cpp/main.cpp", line 1727, in main [0x55f2c6dd80b6]
       1725: 
       1726: 
      >1727:         QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(state.settings.threads -1);
       1728:         auto threadCount = QThread::idealThreadCount();
       1729:         qInfo() << qString(construQt);
       1730:         qInfo() << qString("------------------- | CPU Information | ------------------\nSystem has {} cpus\nRequesting {} threads\n", qString(threadCount), qString(state.settings.threads));
#0    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6.2.4", at 0x7f07043aea50, in QThreadPool::setMaxThreadCount(int)
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [0x8])
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no issue using the std::thread so I have concluded this is an interaction between QThread and glibc 2.34.

Without any further information to provide, my question is simply to see if the community has encountered similar problems between Qt and libc 2.34, specifically with regards to the pthread library.

Happy to provide further details. Here is my main.

```
class Engine : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    void run() override
    {
      qInfo() << "Say Anything";
    }
};

Engine *engine = new Engine();
QThreadPool *threadPool;

if (QThreadPool::globalInstance()) {
  qInfo() << "Is the gloabalInstance there?";
}

threadPool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
threadPool->start(engine); // Will crash
threadPool->setMaxThreadCount(state.settings.threads -1);
```

Comment: That `__libc_start_main` appears in the stack trace is probably not significant.  I would expect that to appear early in pretty much *any* stack trace.

Comment: From what little is presented, my guess would be that `QThreadPool::globalInstance()` has not been initialized to a valid value at the point where `main()` is trying to use it.  I can't speak in any detail to why that might be the case in your particular program, but although I can't rule out the glibc change you mentioned, I think it's more likely that a flaw in the program itself is responsible.

Comment: I recognize that you have framed the question as whether others have observed similar behavior.  If you were interested in help debugging the misbehavior of your particular program, however, then we would be looking for a [mre] that reproduces the behavior.  And preparing one is an excellent debugging exercise in its own right, so it might be worth your while even if you don't present the result to us.

Comment: John. Thank you very much. I agree that this is a strange outcome and would love that it was some error I have made in my implementation of QThreadPool. However, the exact code functions superbly in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. There are no changes to this part of Qt that I can find between Qt5 and Qt6, both of which, anyway crash in a 21.04 or 22.04 env. Is it a coincidence that libc is named here and has been subject to a somewhat large change from 2.33 to 2.34 exactly on the part of the library throwing an error. Is it further suspicious that the Qt6 website does not mention 22.04 as a validated os?

Comment: (1) That the program consistently works as expected in a different version of the OS does not prove that it is error-free.  It is possible for it to be erroneous in a way that happens not to be triggered in some environments, but is triggered in others.  (2) It is no coincidence that `__libc_start_main` appears in your stack trace because, again, I would expect it to appear in *every* stack trace.  It may or may not be a coincidence that your program works in a distro that uses glibc 2.33 and not in one that uses glibc 2.34.

Comment: I added all of main(). Maybe I have missed something aboutQthreadPool

Comment: Note also that glibc 2.34 is backwards *source*-compatible with earlier glibc, but not backwards *binary* compatible, though this is for a different reason than the structural change to (more or less) a single shared library instead of multiple.  Which begs the question: you did recompile for 22.04, right?  A binary built for 18.04 probably will not run on 22.04, though I would expect a different error message if that were tried.

Comment: Yes. of course. gcc 7 to 12 were tried on 22.04 without any change. Note that if I comment out this QThreadPool line a new error in QtConcurrent will spring-up also having to do with globalInstance()...so I will continue to investigate how I manage this object.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "glibc 2.34 is backwards source-compatible with earlier glibc, but not backwards binary compatible" -- that's nonsense. GLIBC is _always_ binary-backwards-compatible.

Comment: Minimal Reproducible example that follows the documentation added to post, main() removed

Comment: The globalInstance() is never instantiated despite that being supposedly an automatic thing for Qt applications. Its just not there.

Comment: Perhaps I worded that poorly, @EmployedRussian, but I am referring to the last sentence of comment 10 here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23323#c10, which may in fact be of particular relevance to the current question.  Indeed no, a dynamically-linked binary built against Glibc 2.34 will not run against earlier Glibc because such binaries will require a `GLIBC_2.34`-versioned `__libc_start_main`.  And this is intentional, because running such a binary against an earlier Glibc would otherwise produce issues with ELF constructors not running.  [Hmm.]